# Possible race condition when checking img.complete in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a jQuery plugin that will execute a function before and after an image loads. Essentially this is so we can show a loading animation when displaying large images.

```
if (typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) { 
    return; // 1
}
// 2
if (!this.complete) {
    options.preload(this); //3

    $(this).load(function () {
        options.loaded(this); //4
    });
}
```

1. Check for images that have failed to load (e.g.404).
2. Check if the image has loaded `this.complete`
3. If not, call the preload function (starts the loading animation)
4. Add the callback for the image `load` event (stops the loading animation)

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, in IE (9) I'm finding that sometimes the `preload` function fires, but not the `loaded` function.

I suspect that this could be a possible race condition.

What's the best way of handling this? Should I just check `this.complete` again after calling the preload function?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when the `load` even handler is attached. If the image is already loaded before attaching the load event handler then the load event is not going to be fired. If you want to avoid such conditions then set the `src` of the image after attaching `load` event handler.

```
$("img").load(function(){

    //Image loaded

}).attr("src", "imageSource");
```

Comment: Setting the src did the trick. This does seem to be an "issue" with IE9. I found this post discussing the same problem. http://nnucomputerwhiz.com/ie9-image-load-event-bug.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 3 boolean conditions to fulfill you can elimate the race condition using a karnaugh map.  A k-map is to simplify boolean expression and to eliminate race conditions, for example if there is an undefined transition.

1. Check for images that have failed to load (e.g.404).
2. Check if the image has loaded this.complete
3. If not, call the preload function (starts the loading animation

Comment: Can you provide an example. What you've posted just looks like what I'm doing already.

Comment: Sure, k-maps are related to gray-codes. wikipedia has a good article about gray codes and the tower-of-hanoi game.